# How to check if list contains particular value in Dart?

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, nested-lists

I want to get true if list contains that value. Currently this code which I have pasted down there it is returning false. I want the value should be true if value exists.

```
   void main() {
  var demo = [
    {123, 1},
    {234, 1}
  ];

  print(demo.contains(123));

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the elements in your list are actually of type Set (Which is kinda like a List in which each object can occur only once.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var list = [123,11,202]; // list of int

list.contains(123); // true


var map = {'id':'123','name':'john'}; 

map.containsValue('123'); // true

var demos = [
    {123, 1},
    {234, 1}
  ];

  print(demos[0].contains(123)); //true

  **//OR**

demos.forEach((demo){
     print(demo.contains(123)); // to check all items
  });
```

i hope it helps

Comment: I would appreciate if you would like to answer this aswell like contains is already a loop then why we need of forEach loop?

Comment: because demos = [{},{}] contains nestedlist,so to check all item you can use forEach()

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response on this. Now I get the point clearly the contains is working as a nested loop for each element inside in the nested list. am I right?

Answer (score 7):

If your want to "pass down" a logic to a list of list, your can try the buildin `.any()` or `.every()` function.

```
void main() {
  var demo = [
    {123, 1},
    {234, 1}
  ];

  print(demo.any((item) => item.contains(123)));
  // output: true
}
```